# "x questions with new activity" no longer available on the main site

Tags: support, bug, status-review

I tend to search for `[azure*]` which enables me to keep tabs on current and new questions I might be able to answer. I've done so for quite some time, and the "x questions with new activity" feature enabled me to distinguish new questions from the ones I already looked at.

In short: Stack Overflow no longer shows me the "x questions with new activity" notification. I've seen this behavior for a few days now.

I've tried with three different browsers: Edge Dev (my daily driver), Edge and Firefox, to eliminate the possibility of this being an Edge Dev specific issue or a Chromium issue.
After that, I opened a tab searching for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) to eliminate the possibility that the `[azure*]` search term would yield too many tags to search for (currently 20), introducing this issue. This also did not provide me with the "x questions with new activity" notification.

Has anything changed? Is there currently an issue? Does anyone know what the reason for this change in behavior is or might be?

Meta *does* show the "x questions with new activity" notification.

Comment: Noticed this issue too.

Comment: I thought it was just me. It seems like the WebSocket that provides this data is no longer working on here. Works fine for me on other SE Sites though

Comment: The SE sockets are, by far, the most unstable websockets I've seen on any established website. The chat sockets frequently blip as well.

Comment: I will admit, I haven't seen this. I frequently have the following [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*+or+ssms*+or+tsql) open and I literally got a "1 question with new activity" about 30 seconds after I read this. Obviously it is happening to others, considering the upvotes, but just noting I haven't personally see it. Might be due to volumes?

Comment: @Larnu that search also doesn't work for me

Comment: Maybe it's browser specific? I'm personally using Firefox 97.0.1.

Comment: @Larnu 98.0b5 here, though I switched from 97 because I thought FF caused the issue

Comment: Odd. It's definitely working for me. [Just had it pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2p4R.png).

Comment: Just tried again, this time using Firefox 97.0.1 and Chrome 98.0.4758.102. Both do not show the notification after I validated there were new items for my search query. Seems to be a scattered issue.

Comment: Under the Java tag I am seeing it from time to time. Under the javascript tag nothing so far even though there are questions rolling in regularly. So "spotty" would be my current opinion.